# How to prove that $L_2[0,\infty)$ space is linearly isomorphic to $\mathcal{H}_2$ the space of analytic in $Re(s)>0$ functions?

Tags: fourier-analysis, control-theory

I want to know how to prove that $L_2[0,\infty)$ space is linearly isomorphic to $\mathcal{H}_2$ the space of analytic in $Re(s)>0$ functions.

Please help me. Thanks very much.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem